# Issue with installing Gems on Mac Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I am new to mac environment and having a tough time installing an existing application locally.

I have setup rvm and we need to use ree-1.8.7

I have tried both bundle install and gem install as well.

I am getting following errors:

```
Resolving dependencies...........
There was a Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError while loading factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec: 
Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x10896c1a8> 3.0.7"] from
  /Users/aditya/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/specifications/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec:32
```

I have already gone through several suggestions on SO and other websites. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Invalid gemspec" messages during "bundle install" of factory girl (rails 3.1 and ruby 1.9.2p290)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928514/invalid-gemspec-messages-during-bundle-install-of-factory-girl-rails-3-1-an)

Comment: I am not sure the other question is for linux environment where as I am on mac.. i am trying to use advice here.. if i get success, i will update my question.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the OS. It is probably an issue with bundler/broken dependencies. Maybe try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928514/invalid-gemspec-messages-during-bundle-install-of-factory-girl-rails-3-1-an#answer-12170207). Anyway, have you googled and tried any solutions so far?

Comment: Yes I have tried a lot and looked all over.. the answer you suggested, as it happens i am trying something on those lines.. i have moved the spec files to another folder and now trying to bundle install.. and it seems like it will go through..

Comment: had you resolved the bundler dependencoes locally?

Comment: majioa i am not sure what you mean..

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be "that guy" but I would strongly recommend *not* beginning development of a new project with REE as it is EOL:

http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/02/21/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-2012-02-released-end-of-life-imminent/

Comment: this is an existing project.. cant help it but go ahead with ree.. for now and i also hope that client decides to migrate !!

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this issue was, I just moved all the files creating these errors into a new sub directory. Then running bundle install went smoothly.

In my case the file was:

```
/Users/aditya/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/specifications/factory_girl_rails-1.7.0.gemspec
```