# Passenger throws Bundler::GemfileError after "gem update --system"

Tags: rvm, bundler, passenger

### Background

On my local machine, I tried installing the 'bullet' gem via my gemfile, and `bundle` seemed to go without incident, however upon restarting my app passenger began throwing the error `Invalid gemspec for uniform_notifier`. It seems someone else had [this issue](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet/issues/58) and the [suggested resolution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9005150/995663) said to update RubyGems by running:

### The issue

```
gem update --system
```

This produced no error messages upon running, however now none of apps will start. They all give the same vague Passenger error:

```
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue. (Bundler::GemfileError)
```

I removed 'bullet' from my gemfile so it's now back in a state when it was working yesterday, so I don't think there can be an error in my gemfile. Furthermore, all of my other apps are now broken and their gemfiles haven't changed at all.

For reference:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]
rails -v
Rails 3.2.6
rvm --version
rvm 1.1.4 by Wayne E. Seguin
```

And when I do `gem list` for the global and local gemsets, it shows **bundler 1.1.0** installed.

**Edit:** I should also mention that running `rails s` starts up a WEBrick server just fine and I can access my apps at localhost:3000, so it's only under Passenger that this error crops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by rolling back rubygems-update to the previously installed version by running

```
gem update --system 1.8.11
```

At which point all of my apps began working again. I'm still not sure what the problem was, and will gladly switch the accepted answer from my own to someone who can provide more insight into why updating rubygems-update would break Passenger integration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you committed your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: No. After removing `gem 'bullet'` from my gemfile and re-`bundle`ing, both my gemfile and gemfile.lock were back in their previous working state, so there was nothing to commit. I haven't committed any changes throughout this whole debacle, and my working directory is clean. So whatever changes `gem update --system` introduced much have happened outside my app(s).

Answer (score 0):

I wish someone from Phusion Passenger would give a definitive answer but just wanted to say that I've experienced the same thing. Updating rubygems has broken passenger-nginx integration for us and requires recompiling the passenger-nginx module. Not sure why this would be. My speculation is that the module is somehow compiled with a hard reference to a specific version of rubygems.