# Invalid gemspec in fnordmetric gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using rails application in ubuntu 11.10.I tried to install fnordmetric gem using this command

```
sudo gem install fnordmetric
```

In the console while installing it showed like this

```
Fetching: bson-1.8.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed fnordmetric-1.0.0
Successfully installed bson-1.8.2
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for fnordmetric-1.0.0...
Installing ri documentation for bson-1.8.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for fnordmetric-1.0.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for bson-1.8.2...
```

I included fnordmetric gem in my gem file as

```
gem 'fnordmetric'
```

after that i did

```
sudo bundle install
```

Gem is installed but in gem list fnordmetric gem is not shown.
I am getting this error when I did script/server.

```
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/fnordmetric-1.0.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0xc821cb4> 0.4.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/home/paddu/Documents/fnordmetric/ts-delayed-delta/ruby/1.8/specifications/fnordmetric-1.0.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x9569204> 0.4.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/home/paddu/Documents/fnordmetric/ts-delayed-delta/ruby/1.8/specifications/fnordmetric-1.0.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x9569204> 0.4.0"]
/home/paddu/Documents/fnordmetric/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:18: Bundler couldn't find some gems.Did you run `bundle install`? (RuntimeError)
    from /home/paddu/Documents/fnordmetric/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/paddu/Documents/fnordmetric/config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
    from /home/paddu/Documents/fnordmetric/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
    from /home/paddu/Documents/fnordmetric/config/boot.rb:122
    from script/server:2:in `require'
    from script/server:2
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds just like this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004804/invalid-gemspec-illformed-requirement-yamlsyckdefaultkey0xb5f9c990-3?rq=1

Comment: But I tried with gem update --system. Still issue is not resolved. So please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: so what's in your gemfile?

Comment: My gem file contains these list of gems                        `source :gemcutter`

`gem "rails", "2.3.14"`
`gem "rack", "~>1.1.0"`
`gem "hpricot", "0.8.3"`
`gem "htmldoc", ">=0.2.3"`
`gem "babosa"`
`gem "paperclip"`
`gem "ruby-saml"`
`gem "thinking-sphinx", ">= 1.3.20", :require => "thinking_sphinx"`
`gem "ts-delayed-delta", ">= 1.1.0", :require => "thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta"`
`gem 'populator', "1.0.0"`
`gem 'faker',"0.9.5"`
`gem 'memcached',"1.4.1"`
`gem 'memcache-client',"1.8.5"`
`gem "coderay"`
`gem "mongrel"`
`mysql-config=/path/to/mysql_config`
`gem "mysql"`
`gem "jammit"`

Comment: fnordmetric gem supports only for ruby1.9 and above versions.? I am using ruby 1.8, Can I use fnordmetric gem for my application( I want to use this gem for analytics purpose).?